# how can i fix the error with the "ivector" folder from vosk model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, model, vosk

I wanted to run my Vosk voice recognition project but got this error. How can I fix this?

```
ERROR (VoskAPI:DecodableNnetLoopedOnlineBase():decodable-online-looped.cc:50) Ivector feature dimension mismatch: got -1 but network expects 40
```

In folder "model" from Vosk I have the files:

[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBofH.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.